# Does not save into correct database

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-2012

I have created a diagram with sql server 2012, wich contains the table Account.
From there i created the dbml in my project to acess the DB and tables.
I sucessfuly managed to create a control and model based on my database and create a account using all the required fields in my DB.
If i use the view method to check the database, it does show all the accounts that i created, but if i try to view it through SQL server 2012 it appears to be empty.

I have checked the connection string and the debug allows me to see that the Create Post method is being called and using the correct model.

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Accounts.ToList());
    }

public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Account account)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Accounts.Add(account);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(account);
    }
```

This are the default methods from the MVC4. I do know that my DB is being used, since i do have the specific fields from it, but not recording into it.

How can i find where the data is being stored?

I would apreciate the logic behind the solution so i can avoid future errors like this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried *anything* to diagnose the problem? Debugging, verifying connection string, Sql Server profiling, verifying web server logs, etc, etc... ?

Comment: Are you sure your Create POST is called?  You've shown your Index GET method, but not the Create GET

Comment: Are you getting any model validation error? Debug your app to check if the Create method is called. Check if the connection string is correct?

Comment: Crono i did used debug to check if my Create function was being called, and it is, allong with a variable to check the contents of the database before saving new info there, it showed me all the data that i get on the view, and that it was coming from my models. The connection string is correct, and im calling the right datacontex, im trying atm sql server profiling, i never used it.

Jonesy, yes, its defenitly calling the Post and not Get. i just didnt post the Create Get, ill edit the topic in a min

ARS No im not getting any sort of errors.

Answer (score 0):

By default, your database file create in system AppData folder. You should change connection string in the web.config file. for example:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
        connectionString="server=.\SQLEXPRESS;database=mydb;integrated security=true" />
</connectionStrings>
```